# Ubuntu 22.04 slow to dismount Garmin GPS

Tags: usb, unmount, gps

I have a Garmin eTrex 30 GPS which appears to a host computer as a USB flash drive, or more precisely like two drives, one for the device's internal memory and the other for its MicroSD expansion card.  This worked fine under Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and allowed me to transfer GPX files (tracks and waypoints) out or maps and routes in.

Under 22.04, connection and data transfer continues to work correctly, but clicking the Unmount button or selecting Eject causes Ubuntu to display the warning "Writing data ... the device should not be unplugged" for an indefinite period of time, at least five minutes.  This happens even when I have not written anything to the device.  Normally I give up in disgust and pull out the USB cable anyway after thirty seconds or so.

dmesg reports the following when the eTrex is plugged in:

```
[46887.498981] usb 1-2.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[46887.582986] usb 1-2.3.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[46895.694932] usb 1-2.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[46896.190917] usb 1-2.3.1: device not accepting address 17, error -32
[46920.010761] usb 1-2.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[46920.123869] usb 1-2.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=091e, idProduct=2519, bcdDevice= 5.09
[46920.123885] usb 1-2.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=5
[46920.123892] usb 1-2.3.1: SerialNumber: 0000e4ed7a4a
[46920.128048] usb-storage 1-2.3.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[46920.128320] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-2.3.1:1.0
[46921.152451] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Garmin   GARMIN Flash     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[46921.153423] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Garmin   GARMIN Card      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[46921.154100] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[46921.155136] sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[46921.156492] sd 7:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[46921.158386] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] 3907584 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
[46921.160372] sd 7:0:0:1: Power-on or device reset occurred
[46921.164399] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdf] 3987456 512-byte logical blocks: (2.04 GB/1.90 GiB)
[46921.168536] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[46921.168547] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[46921.169890] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[46921.169904] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdf] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[46921.172770] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[46921.173874] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[46921.204897]  sdf: sdf1
[46921.211648]  sde:
[46921.226755] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[46921.229745] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
[46924.066200] FAT-fs (sde): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[46925.340299] FAT-fs (sdf1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

(I did run fsck and it found only a "harmless" difference between the boot sector and its backup, plus the dirty bit being set.)

Ejecting /dev/sde gives the following dmesg output, with Ubuntu (1) apparently thinking the GPS is a rotating medium(!), and (2) repeating the same hopeless sequence of actions repeatedly:

```
[47205.939981]  sde:
[47256.893229] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: hpet wd-wd read-back delay of 375955ns
[47256.893267] clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 436088ns, clock-skew test skipped!
[47346.911845]  sde:
[47393.254086]  sde:
[47408.077282]  sde:
[47479.867714] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU3: hpet wd-wd read-back delay of 404800ns
[47479.867728] clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 436088ns, clock-skew test skipped!
[47526.340704] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[47527.354518] ..................................................................................................not responding...
[47626.687513] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[47626.687527] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[47626.687532] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[47626.687541] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[47626.690256] sde: detected capacity change from 3907584 to 0
[47626.703490] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[47627.737819] ......................................................
[47682.874249] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: hpet wd-wd read-back delay of 375955ns
[47682.874264] clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 436088ns, clock-skew test skipped!
[47683.033410] ............................................not responding...
[47727.071274] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[47727.071287] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[47727.071292] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[47727.083279] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[47728.125093] ..................................................................................................not responding...
[47827.454163] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[47827.454178] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[47827.454185] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[47828.174947] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[47829.208344] ..................................................................................................not responding...
[47928.541872] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[47928.541885] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[47928.541891] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[47928.558731] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[47929.591651] ....................
[47949.880341] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU3: hpet wd-wd read-back delay of 436088ns
[47949.880355] clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 405288ns, clock-skew test skipped!
[47950.071452] ..............................
```

At that point I unplugged the USB cable.  Likely related: at some point during this period, Ubuntu 22.04 "experienced an internal error", namely udevadm crashed with SIGABRT in __GI___ioctl().

Has anyone else seen behavior like this, or have suggestions about how to make it work properly?

Comment: I have the same problem with a Garmin Etrex 22x.